# How can I open an Angular 7 app in Visual Studio for Mac 2019?

Tags: angular7, visual-studio-mac

After completing a tutorial in Visual Studio Code, I can open up both my Angular app and my Web Api app, in Visual Studio Code for Mac, using a single line of code in a terminal window 'code .' where I'm in the parent folder for both the two projects.

This opens both projects up in Visual Studio Code and I can then run 'ng serve' and 'dotnet run' from terminals within VS Code.

Now I want to open both these projects in Visual Studio for Mac 2019, under a single solution, but can only seem to open up the Web Api app.

Is there an equivalent of 'code .' for Visual Studio for Mac 2019 that will open up both project folders in a solution? Or is there another way to open up the Angular SPA app in a solution in Visual Studio for Mac 2019? And then run it from Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac is solution based and does not support opening folders by themselves. Not sure how you created the Angular project. If you did `dotnet new angular` then you end up with a .csproj file for the ASP.NET Core project and the SPA app is in a ClientApp folder. Opening that .csproj in Visual Studio for Mac will create a new solution file and you can see both the ASP.NET Core project and the Angular SPA application.  think all you are missing would be to move the Angular SPA app to a folder inside the ASP.NET Core project so the files are automatically found on solution open.

Comment: I didn't use dotnet to create the Angular app. I used Angular cli in my terminal window => 'ng new myApp'. So there is no csproj file associated with the Angular app.

Comment: I'm only guessing now, but looking at other threads it looks like I might have to create a dotnet Angular project and then manually move files into that project and modify other config like files to have everything work correctly! ??? I wish there was another way but I haven't figured it out yet.